# SQL - Find not distinct values with two criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

Pretty much it is easier to show, than to explain:

I have the following table:

[image]

The idea is, that I need only the "Objekts", for which I have entered the Datum within the same month.
E.g., "aaa" is needed, because I have data for August twice. "bbb" is not needed, because I have once for August and once for Septermber, which is OK.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT objekt,count(*) as counter
FROM tempt_report
GROUP BY objekt
HAVING count(*)>1
```

But obviously, I do not mention the requirement for the "Datum", and thus I do not get what I want.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Is `Datum` data type is `DATETIME` ?

Comment: @Arulkumar it is "date"

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL 2014. . . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourDate DATE,YourObjekt VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ({d'2016-08-01'},'aaa')
,({d'2016-08-31'},'aaa')
,({d'2016-08-31'},'bbb')
,({d'2016-09-01'},'aaa')
,({d'2016-09-02'},'bbb');

WITH PartitionedCounted AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YourObjekt,YearAndMonth ORDER BY YourDate) AS Nr
          ,YearAndMonth
          ,YourDate
          ,YourObjekt
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),YourDate,102) AS YearAndMonth) AS A
)
SELECT pc.YearAndMonth,pc.YourObjekt,tbl.YourDate
FROM PartitionedCounted AS pc
INNER JOIN @tbl AS tbl ON tbl.YourObjekt=pc.YourObjekt AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),tbl.YourDate,102)=pc.YearAndMonth
WHERE pc.Nr > 1
```

### UPDATE

Since you are using SQL Server 2014 you can use `EOMONTH`:

```
WITH PartitionedCounted AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YourObjekt,EOMONTH(YourDate) ORDER BY YourDate) AS Nr
              ,EOMONTH(YourDate) AS EOM
              ,YourDate
              ,YourObjekt
        FROM @tbl AS tbl
    )
    SELECT pc.EOM,pc.YourObjekt,tbl.YourDate
    FROM PartitionedCounted AS pc
    INNER JOIN @tbl AS tbl ON tbl.YourObjekt=pc.YourObjekt AND EOMONTH(tbl.YourDate)=pc.EOM
    WHERE pc.Nr > 1
```

Comment: This looks nice and obviously works, better than expected. However, I am having a little trouble to fix it according to my requirements. Can you note the error? http://pastebin.com/YRBQfty6

Comment: At the end this is how I made it work:http://pastebin.com/wxMB3E2b Thanks once again for showing "Initial Date", although it was not in the expected result! :)

Answer (score 2):

not sure if I'm missing something!  You want >1 of any type in a month of a year

```
SELECT objekt,year(datum),month(datum),count(*) as counter
FROM tempt_report
GROUP BY objekt, year(datum),month(datum)
HAVING count(*)>1
```

Comment: Exactly! Simple and small! :)

Comment: Edit: Actually, you give just one result pro Object, and not two as needed. But still, good one :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT objekt,dateadd(month,DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, datum),0) m
   FROM tempt_report
   GROUP BY objekt,DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, datum)
   HAVING count(*)>1
```

Comment: That is half true. I get just the object column with this approach, not the datum column.

Comment: I cleaned it a bit. hope it fixes all.

Answer (score 1):

```
select MONTH(Datum) +' '+ YEAR(Datum) AS Datum,
       objekt,
       COUNT(1) from #tempt_report
GROUP by objekt,YEAR(Datum), MONTH(Datum)
HAVING count(1) > 1
```

You can try this query?

Comment: Hi! I have tried it, I get three columns and the datum is just in a year format... And it is 2025 :)

Comment: select DateName(MONTH,DateAdd(MONTH,MONTH(Datum),0)-1) +' '+ CONVERT(nvarchar,YEAR(Datum)) AS Datum,
    objekt,
    COUNT(1) from #tempt_report
GROUP by objekt,YEAR(Datum), MONTH(Datum)
HAVING count(1) > 1

Hi. Soryy about that.
it will work for you